# 'Application tried to present modally an active controller' with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

This problem has been answered using objective C and tab view controllers. I can't figure out how to solve this problem of presenting modally to an active controller when the app tries to return to the home screen.

The series of view controllers for making a post is launched by a button on the top of my app's home screen. All view controllers are presented with the method: present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil).

I read here that I have to dismiss the view controller that is trying to bring the user back to the home screen. If I write a line of code for dismissing that view controller, it brings me to the view controller immediately preceding it, which is not the home screen. How do I get my app to present the home screen from the end of a series of view controller for making a post without triggering this error?

I know that this has been previously answered in different contexts, but they didn't appear able to help me solve this problem. Would greatly appreciate some fresh eyes on this to help me solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can dismiss all view controllers instead of showing home screen over them.

```
var controller = presentingViewController
while let presentingVC = controller?.presentingViewController {
    controller = presentingVC
}
controller?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: awesome, it worked for me where I have a home screen button and I want to take user to home screen on press of that button